# How to update a CartoDB table at a certain time of day

Tags: postgresql, carto

I have a table in CartoDB 'inland' that I would like to have automatically update each day at 8pm PST.  I know that PostgreSQL has no internal function to run an UPDATE COLUMN function at a certain time of day.  Is there a way to use Cron or PgAgent to do this?  Would I need to setup CartoDB on my local machine instead of only using the webservice?

Comment: Can't you use a cron in your machine that calls the webservice to do the update th?e

Comment: For the cron to work would I need to leave my computer on and be logged into Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered setting up an UPDATE sql query through a URL such as:

```
http://{account}.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q=UPDATE INTO test_table (column_name) VALUES ('value')&api_key={Your API key}
```

and then setting up a schedule timer to visit that URL at a specific time of day?

Comment: I have not considered doing that as I didn't know that was an option.  How does that work?  Also how would I setup a scheduled timer in my table? It sounds promising though.

Comment: You can find more info on SQL URL queries here [link](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api.html). Basically whenever that URL is visited it will run the query. As far as setting up a timer, it depends on your computer system but I know you can setup a scheduled event in Windows which will tell windows to open the browser and navigate to a specific URL.